# Text area on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a java success coded like this

```
    success:function(response){
            $("#responds").prepend(response);
            $("#contentText").val(''); //empty text field on successful
        }
```

how can i add a textarea in here?

Comment: do you mean add a textArea element to the page in the success function?

Comment: is `#responds` a textarea? please provide more info

Comment: yes, i want to add another text area element inside the #responds in the success function

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add textarea like this:

```
$("#responds").prepend("<input type='textarea' value='" + response + "'/>");
```

This is assuming that `$("#responds")` references a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities to do this:

First: put a textarea in the response you're sending back.

Second: use `$("#responds").prepend("<textarea>" + response + "</textarea>");`