# Adding text area after the ajax call is success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which has drop down. Once I select the drop down, the text are has to displayed with the concerned drop down values. I am using flask,jquery,jinja and html.I am adding whatever I have tried here.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select name="select1" class="form-control" id="select1" style="width:200px; height:30px;" required>
        <option value="">Select the below option</option>
        {% for each_round in round_names %}
        <option value="{{each_round.round_id,each_round.round_name}}">{{each_round.round_name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field</div>
    <div id="resultDiv">
        {{results}}
        <textarea name="rdesc" id="rdesc" style="width:200px; height:300px;" required>{{results}}</textarea>
    </div>
</div>

$("select[name='select1']").change(function() {
    var dropdownValue = document.getElementById("select1");
    var roundName = dropdownValue.options[dropdownValue.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(roundName);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/roundname/get-description',
        data: {
            'round_name': roundName
        },
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            $("textarea[id='resultDiv']").html(results);
        }
    })
})
```

What is happening is:
1. Empty text area is display when I land on the form itself
2. After I select the drop down value, the concerned value are not displaying

What I need is:
1. Text area should not get displayed unless I select the drop down
2. Once I select the drop down the text area should get displayed with data.

I tried this also
[Text area on ajax success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812883/text-area-on-ajax-success)

Comment: The textarea is in your html, if you don't want it to show then `display:none` and change when you get success back from the ajax call - what does `console.log(results)` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that for hiding the textarea you should use the `display:none` property from the css , and if you want **Text area should not get displayed unless I select the drop down**  than just change the **display** property using jquery `$("#id").css("display", "block");` or you can use the jquery predefined methods

1. `$('#id').hide();`
2. `$('#id').show();`

And regarding your another query i.e **Once I select the drop down the text area should get displayed with data.** you should use `$("#rdesc").val(results);` instead of using `$("textarea[id='resultDiv']").html(results);`

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect. Your textarea not have id `resultDiv`. It has id `rdesc` so use that instead and use it in this way, `$("#rdesc").html(results);`

Also note that if results is a JSON object then you need to access the property of that JSON you wish to show in the textarea. Something like this:

```js
var results = {a: 10};
$("#rdesc").html(results.a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="rdesc"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi I changed it,it's not working.I am not seeing the results value in text area

Comment: @GuruKrishna, Could you please log your ajax response and add it in your question

Comment: @GuruKrishna please add the response of AJAX

Comment: But I need the text area should not get displayed until i select the drop down,is there any way to do

Comment: @GuruKrishna You can initially set the textarea as `display: none;` and then in the `success` function just do `$("#rdesc").show()`

Comment: For hiding and showing, you can refer this simple fiddle link (making block as `hidden` initially): https://jsfiddle.net/smahajan89/yd2g7b41/